# How to change swap memory location from SSD to HDD?

Tags: ssd, swap

Is there a way to change the Swap Memory location?
My Ubuntu is installed on my SSD and I want my swap to be on HDD instead.

Comment: New installs now use swap file. Did you manually create a swap partition? You can use gparted & create new swap on HDD & edit fstab to add that swap as partition you use. But if you have 4GB or more of RAM, you may not use nor need swap anyway. SSD life is now similar to HDD life, and if not using swap it does not matter where it is.

Comment: Welcome to [Ubuntu.se].  **;-)** Please [edit] your question and provide the output to `swapon` and `free --human`.